# No reiniciar conección de socketIO

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Tengo una aplicación echa con `nodeJS` y utilizo `sokcetIO` para le tiempo real, pero el problema es que cada vez que el cliente refresca la pagina dando **F5** o de otra manera , el `socketIO` realiza un evento de desconección y luego reconección al servidor, y se reinician valores en el servidor, como podría evitar que pase esto.

No tengo código echo ni idea de que intentar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: que tipo de valores se reinician? especifica

Comment: en el server tengo un `setInterval` que se ejecuta cada 5 minutos , y cuando se reinician los datos del server se reinicia el `setInterval`

Comment: pues, almacena cada cambio del setInterval en un localStorage o sessionStorage si no es nada que requiera una amplia seguridad, si es algo de seguridad, entonces guardalo en una BD y carga tu setInterval desde el estatus que fue guardado la ultima vez que se ejecuto